# Is the comma in the following sentence before "which" a must? Why?

Tags: grammar, commas

> The short PARs of platypus chromosomes X2–X5 have a significantly higher GC content (one-sided Wilcoxon rank-sum test, P < 0.01) than the SDRs or the longer PARs (Extended Data Fig. 4c) **(,)** which probably reflects strong GC-biased gene conversion that is caused by a high recombination rate.

Is the comma needed in this sentence?

Comment: The rather long and unwieldy sentence could be improved by splitting and starting the second sentence _This probably reflects_.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Or did you make it up?

Comment: You can leave out: that is. Also, this is editing, which we don't do around here. :)

Answer (score 0):

> *The short PARs of platypus chromosomes X2–X5 have a significantly*
> *higher GC content (one-sided Wilcoxon rank-sum test, P < 0.01) than*
> *the SDRs or the longer PARs (Extended Data Fig. 4c),* [*which probably*
> *reflects strong GC-biased gene conversion that is caused by a high*
> *recombination rate*].

So I take it that you're asking if the bracketed relative clause should be a defining one or a non-defining one.

Despite the highly technical nature of the sentence, I'd say it's non-defining, since it appears to refer to the whole of the clause that precedes it, as opposed to one of the preceding noun phrases.

Note that non-defining relatives are not modifiers, but supplements, i.e. additional non-integrated content set apart by punctuation and a slight pause in speech.